# Cant create extra table entries in mysql database tables after I reach a limit of about 10000 entries for mysql database hosted on inodb sql server

Tags: sql, mysql, laravel, innodb, multi-tenant

I have a Laravel application that writes and reads from a mysql database setup on innodb sql serve in ubuntu server. The application is a multi-tenant application and has at least 10 tenancies that performs similar functionalities. However, I realized that one tenancy has over 9980 entries in one of the common tenancy tables. When that particular tenancy tries to add another entry to the table, the whole app crashes but other tenancies can add to their copy copy of that table without any issues because they do not have that number of entries. When this happens the sql service runs at around 190% of processing power and the application can not be used by anyone, including those in other tenancies.

This is the create function

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $form = GeneralSpecimen::find($id);
    $patient = Patient::where('id', $form->patient_id)->first();
    $patientName = $patient->first_name . " " . $patient->last_name;
    $patientNum = $patient->patient_number;
    $patientPhoneNumber = $patient->phone;
    $pathologyNumber = $form->pathology_number;
    $formName = "GeneralSpecimen Form";
    $sms = new SmsHelper();

    // Get current Hostname Tenant Facility
    $hostname  = app(\Hyn\Tenancy\Environment::class)->hostname();
    $tenantFacilityName = $hostname->tenant_facility_name;

    $form->update( $request->except( 'auth_signature' ) );

    $billPat = Bill::where('id', $form->bill_id)->first();

    $new_arr = [];
    if(!is_null($billPat)){
          //* storing the column with clinical module items inside a variable [pathology_number]
        $pathology_number =  $billPat->clinical_module_items;


        //*creating an empty array to store the updated array containing the new pathology number


        //*looping through the clinical_module array to extract the pathology number using the key
        foreach( $billPat->clinical_module_items as $key =>$value){

        //*reassigning the pathology number with the new value
         $value['pathology_number'] =request()->pathology_number;

        //* Pushing the updated value array inside the new empty array created
        array_push($new_arr, $value);
        }
    }
    //*Finally updating the clinical_module column with the new array created
    Bill::where('id',$form->bill_id)->update(['clinical_module_items'=>$new_arr]);

    if( $request->submission_ready != 1 )  $form->update([ 'case_status' => 'pending']) ;

    if( !is_null( $this->getSignature() )  && $request->submission_ready == 1 )
    {   # health facility name for address
        $healthFacility = DB::table('health_facility_profiles')->first();
        $healthFacility == null ? $address = $tenantFacilityName : $address = $healthFacility->name_of_facility;
        $form->update([ 'auth_signature' =>  $this->updateSignature( auth()->guard('api')->user()->id ) ]) ;

        # update patient with the new generated password
        //$patient->update(['password' => password_hash($this->password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)]);

        if( !is_null($patient->email) )
        {  # send email
            Mail::to($patient->email)->send(new PatientEmail($patientName, $patient->test_password, $patientNum, $hostname->tenant_facility_name));
        }
        if($sms->isEnabled == 1 && $sms->bundle > 1)
        {   # send sms
           $sms->sendSpecimenReadySms($patientPhoneNumber, $patientName, $pathologyNumber, $formName, $address, $patient->test_password, $patientNum);
        }

        if(!is_null($patientPhoneNumber))
        {  #send WhatsAppMessage
           $sms->sendSpecimenReadyWhatsAppMessage($patientPhoneNumber, $patientName, $pathologyNumber, $formName, $address, $patient->test_password, $patientNum);
        }

        $form->update([ 'case_status' =>  'ready' ]);
        $message = "Specimen updated successfully. An SMS has been sent to Patient";
        return response(compact('message'), 200);

    }
    else if( is_null( $this->getSignature() ))
    {
        $message = "Kindly Upload Your Digital Signature to Finalize this Report" ;
        return response(compact('message'), 200);
    }

    $message = "Specimen form updated" ;
    return response(compact("message"), 200);




}
```

other tenancies that have not reached similar number of entries use the same functions to create new entries without any problem

I inspected the table information in workbench and realized that the total size estimate in is only 6.5 MiB. On deleting some entries, I could add more forms to the app without any problems but once I reach the initial number, the app breaks.

Comment: App crashes or MySQL crashes?

Comment: 1. You can increase the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to allow more data to be cached in memory. 2. Analyze the table schema and ensure that it is properly optimized. Check if there are any unnecessary indexes or columns with large data types that could be reduced.

Comment: Show us the query that causes the crash, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table(s) involved.

Comment: Mysql  service on the server increases to around 190% or 200% and that makes it unresponsive, hence breaking the connection between mysql hence causing the app to crush

Comment: @RickJames
I have added the create function

Comment: Sorry, but I need the SQL.

Comment: @DivineTeyi What is the tablename that is failing to add rows when more than ~ 10000 existing rows?  Please post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE (your-failing-table-name);  for analysis.

Comment: @RickJames
Please there's no TEXT log file that records the error
As a matter of fact, there is no error message displayed in the networks tab when I inspect

Comment: Do you have any column declared `DECIMAL(4)`?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score -1):

This is a very broad issue, the few details you have provided do not specifically violate the limitations of your chosen RDBMS, at least by what is documented here: [InnoDB Limitations](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-limitations)

What you haven't investigated is what is causing the spike in the SQL process. It is not likely to be adding a new record alone, it is more likely to be something related to your indexing strategies or how your client is processing the data.

You might find investigation strategies in this article helpful [Chasing a Hung MySQL Transaction: InnoDB History Length Strikes Back](https://www.percona.com/blog/chasing-a-hung-transaction-in-mysql-innodb-history-length-strikes-back) but you really need to identify if it is your app that is spamming the database and thus causing the performance degradation or if it is the database alone.

- As a thought experiment, if you added the entites manually via SQL, with the app not connected at all, would you still see the issues? If not then this is 100% application logic related, even if the CPU is showing SQL usage, it is the application runtime that is driving the database, not the database itself.

10K records is remarkably small for a database, 6MB sounds very small indeed, so I doubt this is a problem with the database itself and likely related to something at the application layer.

---

### Update

When you see spikes in SQL CPU usage, that can indicate that there is at least one long running query, so you need to query the database or the logs to identify which queries are holding everything up. Read through [TRACKING MYSQL QUERY HISTORY IN LONG RUNNING TRANSACTIONS](https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2015/01/22/tracking-mysql-query-history-in-long-running-transactions/) for advice on how to do this or search for other techniques to inspect your active queries.

> **NOTE:** If your DB is non-responsive you may need to implement a query logging strategy to diagnose this. Find out the very last line of code in the application before the failure and what is the current and recent SQL queries that have been sent to the database.

Arbitrary item thresholds like this are often artifacts of inefficient looping or rebalancing operations across a dataset, especially when there are triggers or other recursive operations involved.

Comment: Thanks for the response Chris.
The issue is there is a thresh hold that the number of entries can't cross.
If I delete one entry from database, the app allows me to create only one new entry. Deleting five old entries means I can only add five new entries. The problem is there seems to be a threshold for the number of entries that can be added and once it reach that threshold, and attempt to add more entries crushes the application

Comment: Adding fields manually to the database breaks nothin. It seems to work very well. The only time I get that error is when create an entry from the application. At the moment sql spikes to almost 200% of cpu usage and that crashes the whole application. However, other tenants on the application can add data their tables without any issues because the number of entries has not reached the threshold causing the error

Comment: It seem to me you need to get in touch with whoever developed the application to find our WHERE the limit exists so you can raise the limit in an orderly manner.

Comment: Just trying to help @DivineTeyi but its out of scope at this stage to post the content from those links. Hopefully they guide you towards your solution. You will probably benefit from some 1:1 mentoring or tech help on this, these issues are usually very quick to diagnose.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller Please this is exactly what I need right now. Please can you help or have suggestions on where to find help?